# Python For Loop Create DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Hihi, I'm reasonably new to Python, more a R guy. But I'm required to use python for a task.

However, I encountered a situation where I need to subset data into different dataFrame by the date.
"in future not 3 exactly, therefore want to create a loop to do this"
I want to potentially create 3 dataframes like

```
df_train_30 which contains start day  0 - 30
df_train_60 which contains start day 30 - 60
df_train_90 which contains start day 60 - 90
```

but not sure how to achieve this... pls help.

idea in code below

```
today = pd.to_datetime('now')
df_train['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['START_DATE'])
previous_day_del = 0

for day_del in (30,60,90):
    **'df_train_' + str(day_del)** = df_train[(df_train['START_DATE']>= today - timedelta(days=day_del)) & (df_train['START_DATE']< today - timedelta(days=previous_day_del))]
    previous_day_del = day_del
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output. I'm guessing it has to be as a dataframe?

Comment: yes, my expected output is having 3 different data frames like 1) df_train_30: contains results of START_DATE between SYSDATE - 30 to SYSDATE,
2) df_train_60: contains results of START_DATE between SYSDATE - 60 to SYSDATE -30, 3) df_train_90: contains results of START_DATE between SYSDATE - 90 to SYSDATE -60

Answer (score 1):

You could probably store it into a **dictionary** - it's easier to manage rather than dynamically generated variables. A dictionary's more of an object with key-value pairs, and the values can be of almost any type, including even dataframes. [Here's a quick guide on Python dictionaries that you could look at.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary)

In your example, you could probably go ahead with this:

```python
today = pd.to_datetime('now')
df_train['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['START_DATE'])
previous_day_del = 0
   
# Creating an empty dictionary here called dict_train
dict_train = {}

for day_del in (30,60,90):
    dict_train[day_del] = df_train[(df_train['START_DATE']>= today -timedelta(days=day_del)) & (df_train['START_DATE']< today - timedelta(days=previous_day_del))]
    previous_day_del = day_del
```

Hope this helps, cheers! :)

Comment: thousand thanks! Yes, exactly what I needed.  thanks for the dictionaries link. was wondering how to turn dictionary back to df but seems found in there.